# Remove the same occurrence of specific characters

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I want to remove "OB" from the string that i put before every vowel.
For example: "THIS IS SOME REALLY GREAT BOLD TEXT" & after adding OB to it: "THOBISOBISSOBOMOBEROBEOBALLYGROBEOBATBOBOLDTOBEXT"
That is the method that i wrote.

```
public static String unObify(String param) {

    String deleteOB = param.replaceAll("[OB]", "");

    return deleteOB;

}
```

Output: THISISSMEREALLYGREATLDTEXT

but the problem is that this method also remove O and B inside my String. and i only want to remove OB which occurs one after the other.

Comment: There is no space in your example input. Your code will work for this :
"THOBIS OBIS SOBOMOBE ROBEOBALLY GROBEOBAT BOBOLD TOBEXT"

Comment: String deleteOB = param.replaceAll("OB", ""); write it instead

Comment: Just `replace("OB","")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current regex `[OB]`, you specify a character class which matches `O` or `B`.

If you want to replace `OB` before every vowel, you could use positive lookahead to assert what follows is a vowel:

[`OB(?=[AEIOU])`](https://regex101.com/r/eVyNno/2)

Or as @Tim Biegeleisen pointed out, use make the lookahead case insensitive:

[`OB(?=(?i)[AEIOU](?-i))`](https://regex101.com/r/eVyNno/3)
or
[`OB(?=[aeiouAEIOU])`](https://regex101.com/r/eVyNno/4)

```
public static String unObify(String param) {

    String deleteOB = param.replaceAll("OB(?=[AEIOU])", "");

    return deleteOB;

}
```

That would replace

`THOBISOBISSOBOMOBEROBEOBALLYGROBEOBATBOBOLDTOBEXT`
to 
`THISISSOMEREALLYGREATBOLDTEXT`

and

`THOBSOBISSOBOMOBEROBEOBALLYGROBEOBATBOBOLDTOBEXT`
to 
`THOBSISSOMEREALLYGREATBOLDTEXT`

Comment: You might want to handle case sensitivity +1.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[]` and write `.replaceAll("OB(?=[AaEeIiOoUu])", "");`.

`[]` means match anything inside `[]` individually